# Routing action controller using reactjs

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <UserMasterList
        getUrl="/User/List"
        getProductionSiteUrl="/User/GetListProductionSite"
        searchUrl="/User/List"
        insertUrl="/User/Regist"
        updateUrl="/User/Update"
        deleteUrl="/User/Delete" />,
    document.getElementById("use-list")
);
```

When run on local, api can call and get data.When enter code here hosting web, alias("xxx") is inserted then api can't call(error 404).
How to use React-Router to route url when insert alias in hosting server.
Please help to me.

Comment: use `Url.Action` helper method for correct url generation

Comment: Because coding in file.tsx, Url.Action can't use.